# Confused with dependency conflict

Tags: android, dependencies, shared-libraries, build.gradle

I have created a library which uses `RecyclerView` and `CardView`.So, i have compiled the dependencies of corresponding in my library `build.gradle` file.And also those dependencies i need to use in my main module also.

When we compile the library in main module the `RecyclerView` and `CardView` will automatically remain accessible from there and no need to add those dependency in my app `build.gradle`.

- I want to clear the confusion is it a fine way or any other better way ?
- Say, if a scenario in one more library i need to add the same dependency  what will do ?
- Finally a stupid query, Can we add dependencies globally in project which is accessible for all the libraries and main module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say, if a scenario in one more library i need to add the same
>   dependency what will do ?

You can add dependencies in sub-module in this case. I always do this and it's working fine in all the case. I don't know it's perfect solution but it's an wrokaround option.

> Finally a stupid query, Can we add dependencies globally in project which is accessible for all the libraries and main module?

You can used Centralize the support libraries dependencies in gradle.

Check this [Gabriele Mariotti Blog](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ad6672902464ee2392d0)